# Backend from Angular 1.x for Angular2

Tags: angular

I am trying to migrate from Angular 1.5 to Angular 2.4.
I have question about backend. Is it possible to use my backend from Angular 1 app to my Angular 2 app without any changes on backend side? 
If answer is yes why i get this error `net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` when trying to log in app on Angular2 ?

Angular 2 code:

```
 login(loginData: User): Observable<User> {
        let data = 'grant_type=password&username=' + encodeURIComponent(loginData.username) + "&password=" + encodeURIComponent(loginData.password);

        return this.http.post(`${this.authUrl}` + 'token', data)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .do(res => {
                if (res.token) {
                    localStorage.setItem('authorizationData', res.token);
                    this.loggedIn = true;
                }
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);    
    }
```

Angular 1 code:

```
function (loginData) {

    var data = "grant_type=password&username=" + encodeURIComponent(loginData.userName) + "&password=" + encodeURIComponent(loginData.password);

$http.post(serviceBase + 'token', data, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } });
```

Comment: Given that APIs don't rely on your frontend implementation, I'd suspect that the answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: Is this a chrome only problem for you ?

Comment: @Seiyria  
Thanks for you opinion, i'll more detailed debugging my app

Comment: @lexith no, same error in mozilla firefox and mozilla dev ed.

Comment: I don't see you adding headers in the ng2 code. Have you tried that with the migrated code? I _think_ ng2 defaults to another content type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you're HTTP POSTing to the same URL? (i.e. that `serviceBase` and `this.authUrl + 'token'` contain the same value?

Why are you NOT setting the `Content-Type` in your Angular 2 code?

Here's how you can do it:

```ts
let headers: Headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
let options: RequestOptionsArgs = { headers: headers };

// ...

return this.http.post(`${this.authUrl}token`, data, options); // `options` has appeared
```

Side note: DON'T do this:

```ts
`${this.authUrl}` + 'token'
```

The point of *template literals* (the backticks) is to AVOID concatenation (the `+` sign).

Instead, you should write this:

```ts
`${this.authUrl}token`
```

Or that:

```ts
this.authUrl + 'token'
```

But not a combination of both. :)